# How can i find sub-field that have a resemble field name in one document MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I want to find many field that each field name're little bit different in one document which the example data is below

```
{
 id:xxx ,
 E20190318_1:{
            a:1,

         },
 E20190318_2:{
            a:1,
            b:5
         },
 ...,
 E20190318_1000:{
            a:2,
            b:2
         },
 E20190319_1:{
            a:1,
            b:2
         },
 ...,
 E20190319_1000:{
            a:0,
            b:6
         },
}
```

what should I do if I want to find all of field E20190318 with nosql mongodb?
 * E20190318 << This is a file name that I made it as object keyname.

`db.getCollection('eg').find({},{$regex:/E20190318/i}).pretty()`

I used to try this command and program return only object ID field to me

Comment: Please expand on what you want (what info you have given is not clear), also elaborate on what "ccc" is

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, please edit your question to make it more clear so that we can help you out.

Comment: I already edit  my example info ccc is just a data in object